# the version angular Nativescript use?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have been working in Angular as a hobby. and now I interested in Nativescript that use Angular typescript. and few days ago Google had released the new version of Angular, Angular 6. If I install Nativescript right now, what version Angular did Nativescript use in their framework?

I don't want to installed if the version is lower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now **NativeScript** supports only upto **angular 5**. Their latest version is [4.0](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-4.0-is-out).

And they still have an [open issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1282) on their GitHub repo for requesting for support for angular 6.

Comment: The latest NS version is 4: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-4.0-is-out. Still support only Angular 5, but you can try with Angular 6.

Comment: Thanks for the update @CalEliacheff, I'll update the answer

Comment: and why NS just support using Andorid 23 ? @AnuradhaGunasekara

Answer (score 0):

The current **version of NativeScript** is using **angular 16.2.0**